# I need to add all of the items in a ListBox into a "total" variable

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Here is an example of the For loop that I'm trying to run where lstCost is my ListBox that is formed by selecting options from two other ListBoxes and calculating a total for those option to create an item total and totalCost is the variable where I'm trying to save the total of all list items.

```
    Dim totalCost As Integer
    For x As Integer = 0 To lstCost.Items.Count - 1
        totalCost += Val(lstCost.Items.Item(x))
    Next
    txtTotalCost.Text = totalCost.ToString
```

For some reason, I end up with a 0 as my total in my txtTotalCost TextBox. Can anybody think of any reason why?

Comment: What happens when you debug this?  What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  `Val` always returns a Double not an integer

Comment: whats in the listbox? Value wise I mean..

Comment: If you know it's integers use totalcost += DirectCast(ListBox1.Items(x), Integer)

Comment: If its $0.25 you will be getting zero... change integer to double

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim totalCost As Double = 0

For x As Integer = 0 To lstCost.Items.Count - 1

    totalCost += DirectCast(lstCost.Items.Item(x).ToString.trim,Double)

Next

txtTotalCost.Text = totalCost.ToString
```

depending on your values in listbox you can change it to `Decimal` if required